# vb.net animating a notification form. Problem with threading and sizing

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms

I have created a class to use as a notification window (similar to toast notifications, which are disabled on our system).
I use a timer object to timeout the closing the form, and a backgroundworker to handle the animation of it sliding in from the bottom of the screen.  For debugging purposes the form just outputs it's own size and the screen bounds.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ASNotify

    Public Sub New(ByVal title As String, ByVal msg As String, ByVal Optional timeout As Integer = 5000)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.Text = title
        Me.NotifyMessage.Text = $"{Me.Width}x{Me.Height}{vbCrLf}{My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Size.Width}x{My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Size.Height}"
        TimeoutTimer.Interval = timeout
        TimeoutTimer.Enabled = True
        AnimationWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AnimationWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles AnimationWorker.DoWork
        Dim xloc As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Size.Width - Me.Width
        Dim yloc As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Size.Height

        For x As Integer = 0 To Me.Height
            MoveWindow(xloc, yloc - x)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(2)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub MoveWindow(xloc As Integer, yloc As Integer)
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(Sub() MoveWindow(xloc, yloc))
        Else
            Location = New Drawing.Point(xloc, yloc)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TimeoutTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimeoutTimer.Tick
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    
End Class
```

I call this from another form by calling

```
Private Sub NotifyUser(ByRef a As Alert.Alert)
    Dim notify As New ASNotify(a.Location, a.Comment, 5000)
    notify.Show()
End Sub
```

I call that sub by pressing a button on the form, and it works perfectly.....Sometimes.

repeatedly triggering the notify window makes it pops up as one of 2 different sizes on the screen, although the contents showing the size always state 264x81 and screenbounds 1920x1040

and occasionally I get an exception that the line saying 'Location = new Drawing.Point(xloc,yloc) is being called from a thread other than that which it was created on, despite the Invoke call.

Comment: Why don't you just use a Timer to perform the transition? You're invoking (try to) the UI Thread anyway. If you really really want to use a BackgroundWorker, pass the Height of the Form to the DoWork handler using its `DoWorkEventArgs`, then update the location in its [ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged) handler: that event is raised in the UI Thread, so no worries about invoking (if you need to invoke the UI Thread, call `BeginInvoke()`, `InvokeRequired` is not needed).

Comment: Didn't quite solve my issue, but re-writing to use begininvoke, and reading up on the errors that produced led me to the solution.
The windows isn't fully realised when the calls are made.  Moved the animation and timer to the Load method, rather than the New method and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the timer-start and animationworker start to the Load method of the form, rather than New.

```
Private Sub ASNotify_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TimeoutTimer.Enabled = True
    AnimationWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried the [AnimateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow) function? Copy the vb.net signature from [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.animatewindow) and give it a try.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. I shall certainly give that a look.